# How is nginx IP defined for remote requests from a server?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have 2 websites on the same server using the same version of WordPress. They both make calls to /wp-cron.php from the server itself. They are both managed by nginx and have very similar setups.

When I look at the access logs, I see the requests coming in to /wp-cron.php.
But, for one website all the requests are logged as coming from 127.0.0.1, while the other website all the requests are logged as the external IP of the server.

What is the cause of this, and how can I make sure all such requests get logged as localhost?

Comment: Did you put one of them in the hosts file?

Comment: I did look at that, but the file contains `127.0.1.1 sambull.org`, while the server logs from that website show `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Actually, adding the other domain to hosts appears to have changed the logs to `127.0.0.1` as well. So, I guess including them in the hosts file results in the requests being treated as 127.0.0.1, regardless of which specific IP address is listed.